# How to free nodes in list of lists in C? (Game)

Tags: c, list, memory, memory-management, nodes

I'm making a game, I put icons in the nodes of the mesh and I'm using this struct:

```
typedef struct node{
    int x,y; //coordinates for graphics.h
    struct node *right, *left, *up, *down;
}Node;
```

I read the file with the icon with this:

```
int** ReadPixelFile(int *width, int *height, char name[50])
{
    FILE *fp;
    char address[150];
    int i, j;
    int **mesh;

    strcpy(address, "./Sprites/");
    strcat(address, nombre);
    strcat(address, ".pix");

    fp = fopen( address, "rb" );

    if(fp == NULL)
    { 
        printf("[Error]: cannot read .pix file\n");
        return 0;
    }

    //Read Width x Height
    fread(width, sizeof(int), 1, fp);
    fread(height, sizeof(int), 1, fp);


    AllocMemory(&mesh, *width, *height); //Here is when I allocate memory

    for(i = 0; i < *width; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < *height; j++)
        {
            fread(*(mesh+ i) + j, sizeof(int), 1, fp);
        }
    }

    fclose(fp);

    return mesh;
}
```

and I'm allocating memory with this:

```
void AllocMemory(int ***mesh, int iWidth, int iHeight)
{
    int i;

    *mesh = (int**)malloc(sizeof(int*)*iWidth);

    for(i = 0; i < iWidth; i++)
        *(*mesh+ i) = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*iHeight);

    if(!**mesh)
    {
        settextstyle(1,1,5);
        setcolor(RED);
        outtextxy(1280/3, 720/2, "Error: NO memory.");
    }
}
```

The thing is that I could play and the icons won't have any problem, here is a screenshot from the game:

https://scontent-dft4-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/15391071_10154209405046985_8141714891735886530_n.jpg?oh=4208ce0da45b76bed3ea5b85c2fbccee&oe=58B7F3CB

(I uploaded it to Facebook because my school won't let me use Imgur and that kind of websites)

The rectangles represent the mesh and that every icon is one of the nodes, with the time I noticed that the game crashed way more often and then almost everytime I loaded the game, my teacher told me that I was running out of memory and he told me to free memory but I don't know how to free memory because he never told us how to do so and also in which part of the game to free the memory, I'm thinking about doing it everytime I call `gameOver()`

```
void gameOver()
{
    setbkcolor(BLACK);
    cleardevice();
    setcolor(RED);
    settextstyle(GOTHIC_FONT, HORIZ_DIR, 7);
    outtextxy(640-textwidth("Game Over")/2, 360-textheight("Game Over")/2, "Game Over");
    settextstyle(GOTHIC_FONT, HORIZ_DIR, 3);
    outtextxy(640-textwidth("Press any letter to try again")/2, 600-textheight("Press any letter to return")/2, "Press any letter to return");


    if(kbhit())
    {
        setactivepage(0);
        cleardevice();
        Core(LIVES); //This is like the main function of the game
    }
}
```

In `Core()` I call `ReadPixelFile()` and that is when I allocate memory... So should free the memory before I call `Core()` and run the game again? Please help, the game is complete and I just need to free up memory so it won't crash.

Thank you.

Comment: Any memory you allocate dynamically, such as via `malloc()`, should be freed via `free()` when your program no longer needs it.  That's how you free memory.

Comment: Thanks! @JohnBollinger so should I free ALL the nodes or just the nodes with the icon in it?

Comment: You should free every dynamically-allocated object when you no longer need it.  This is not a function of the objects' types or values, but only of their future (non-)use.

Comment: Creating a function to free() all dynamic memory would be incredibly useful. You could insert it into your gameOver() function, but then also if your game runs in a loop, you can call it from the game as well to make sure you don't run out of memory mid-game - that would certainly stink if you have a big high-score going :P Note: calling cleanup during your game loop might cause a performance hit

Comment: @DanielSiebert How can I create that function to free() to call it mid-game and that doesn't delete all the icons?

Comment: Late to respond - but you would use have a flag on your icon to note if it can be freed or not, if it's no longer need it, you mark the flag as true (since C doesn't support bools natively, use 0 and 1) and only free those with the flag set to true, otherwise leave them

Answer (score 1):

In many cases, this simple trick allows to deallocate memory in C quickly and prevent leaks:

Instead of using plain malloc or calloc, make a simple wrapper (call it MALLOC for example) which will add a link field to allocated blocks, and keep internal list of all blocks.
When you need to free the whole mess, go thru this list and call free() on every item.

Variant: when you know the maximum size, instead of a list, pre-allocate a large buffer and use just one pointer to allocate from this buffer. You can have several such pools for several purposes.
To free everything, just free the large buffer. Or keep it and reuse, if you want to run another iteration of the program.

It looks that in your situation this can work.

/* Teachers of C courses hate this trick because they think it promotes laziness. For me this is example of pragmatic engineering, targeted to prevent certain problem rather than letting it in and debugging later. */

Code example for a "big buffer" variant:

```
    /* somewhere in your main() */
    unsigned pool_size = 100000; /* maximum size */
    unsigned pool_allocated = 0;
    char *pool_ptr = (char*)malloc(pool_size);
    assert(pool_ptr);
    ....

    // Allocation function:
    void* my_alloc(unsigned size)
    {
       char *p;
       if (size == 0) 
           return NULL;
       if ( (pool_allocated + size) > pool_size )
          return NULL;
       p = &pool_ptr[pool_allocated];
       pool_alocated += size;
       return (void*)p;
    }


    void recycle_memory(void)
    {
        pool_allocated = 0; //that's simple :)
    }
```

Comment: Will you help me to implement this trick? It sound pretty cool I'm new to this memory thing and our teacher just teached us how to allocate it. Thank you for the answer bro.

Comment: OMG, thank you so much! I'm gonna use that code and see if it works